# Create link with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I'm trying to generate a link (a-element) with JavaScript, but it just doesn't work. Even though I append the element to the body. Nothing is being displayed. I found various examples, but nothing seems to work.

```
function getLink(){
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.title = "text";
            a.innerHTML = a.title;
            a.href = "http://example.com";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
        }
```

Comment: What did Firebug have to say about it? Did you inspect the DOM? What other debugging have you performed?

Comment: Works here.. http://jsfiddle.net/vmDfk/

Comment: Well I use Ajax for exchanging data between JavaScript and PHP, but aside from that I'm not really experienced with jQuery.

Comment: @user854699: AJAX is not an invention of jQuery.

Comment: No errors in Firebug. You can have a look yourself here: http://poirecognition.konscio.de/androidVideo.html

Comment: @user854699: Vache demonstrates the testcase, and the testcase works.

Comment: -1 Your code snippet works just fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/SjsJy/ Also, as an advice, try to use useful function names. You are not "getting" a link, but "creating" one. Name your function accordingly, for example "createLink".

Comment: Using Firebug, the code works fine for me on any website.

Comment: Try adding it to a specific element inside of the body, instead of directly on the body...

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a issue with this JavaScript code, do you have an example page that produces this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the page you linked us to in comments](http://poirecognition.konscio.de/androidVideo.html):

```
<body onload="getVideo"></body>
```

`getVideo` is not a function call.

Write:

```
<body onload="getVideo()"></body>
```

---

<sup>Notice how Vache posted a testcase containing the snippet you gave us, and was able to *immediately* prove that the function `getVideo` works. Then all it took was finding what other Javascript was involved, and that was just *eight characters*, leading to this solution. **Basic debugging!**</sup>

---

Further thoughts collated from around the question:

- `innerText` would be more appropriate than `innerHTML`; conceptually you're defining what the user should see, not what markup should produce it. Because of this, `innerText` will also escape HTML entities for you.
- `getVideo` is a poor name for a function that does not "get" anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you've provided is all that's being run, nothing will happen.

You haven't explicitly *called* the function `getLink`.

Adding:

```
getLink();
```

the line after your ending curly brace runs successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a div on the page, and add the link to the div. Also, try using innerText instead of innerHTML.

```
var div = document.getElementById("div1");
if (div)
{
    var a = document.createElement('a');    
    a.title = "text";            
    a.innerText = a.title;            
    a.href = "http://example.com";            
    div.appendChild(a);
}
```

Comment: Yea, `innerText` is definitely more appropriate here.